# transparent image in page

Tags: jquery, css

how to make a transparent image with jquery or css?
Is it a possible?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? jQuery/CSS can't "make" images. Do you already have an image with you?

Comment: use raphael.js for creating images with canvas elements. also try PHP image creation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at the CSS `opacity` property. As always, this is not compatible with IE, where you have to use `filter:alpha`.

See here for a couple of examples: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just open Adobe, create new canvas, size x*y, transparent background, save for web & devices as *.png with transparency enabled.

Casablanca is right. Most you can do with css and jquery is use alpha properties to make it see-through. But it's easier to just upload a transparent image.

Comment: Remember that not all browsers support PNG transparency. Also, any graphical software will do, no need to use for Photoshop (I assume that's what you mean with Adobe) to save as png.

Comment: If you don't need high detail around image edges, you can also use GIF images with transparency to reduce both file size and maintain accessibility.

Comment: oops. forgot to specify "adobe".

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of methods to get transparency in your web design. A good break down of the possibilities exists here:

http://css-tricks.com/transparency-in-web-design/

Bob